# A Fifo queue with fast insertion , deletion and get front element java

Tags: java, queue

Which data structure should I use in java to implement a queue with fast insertion at end , deletion from front , and get operation for the first element?

Comment: You can say that. I have implemented it with ArrayLists . Can i make it faster with any other data structure?

Comment: `ArrayDeque` does pretty much exactly this.

Comment: ArrayDeque works slower than ArrayList...I just tried

Comment: @Nikhil Are you talking about pure speed? Or are you talking about worst-case run times?

Comment: I am doing the following operations : when i call "insert" : A copy of the current data structure class(eg:ArrayDeque or ArrayList) is created and an element is added to it and returned. So on the whole, the speed depends on 2 factors: Time taken to create a copy of the object and to insert element to it. So i need a data structure with less space complexity and time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't a `LinkedList` fit the bill?

Its implementation

```
public E remove() {
    return removeFirst();
}

public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}
```

It has both `first` and `last` nodes, so insertion is fast at end. You can delete from front with the method `remove()`. You can get the first element as well, ie. `peek()` which returns the `first` node. That's also `O(1)`.

Source

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

Comment: The deletion on a linked list will be bad. EDIT: Unless he just meant deleting from the front, in which case, my fault.

Comment: @sdasdadas Deletion from front is O(1). If that is the true requirement, we're good.

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry, I misread.

Comment: No...LinkedList is slower than ArrayList in insertions and deletions.I know how to implement a queue. I want to know how I can do it fast.Very fast.

Comment: @Nikhil Look at the source code for `LinkedList`. The `linkLast(E)` method is `O(1)`. That's as fast as you will get.

Comment: LinkedList is not thread safe, you will have to synchronize it externally. Implementations of BlockingQueue is thread-safe. Fastest queue is ConcurrentLinkedQueue if you don't want blocking behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

[LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) does the job.  `take()` to fetch `put()` to insert.

If your queue is a fixed size, [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) will be more efficient.

Or, if you must implement a fast fixed-size queue yourself:

```
public class Queue<T> {
    private T[] q;
    private int head = 0;
    private int tail = 0;
    private int used = 0;
    private int size;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Queue(int size) {
        q = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.size = size;
    }
    public synchronized void put(T o) throws InterruptedException {
        while(isFull()) {
            wait();
        }
        q[head] = o;
        head = (head+1) % size;
        used++;
        notifyAll();
    }
    public synchronized T take() throws InterruptedException {
        while(isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }
        T result = q[tail];
        tail = (tail+1) % size;
        used--;
        notifyAll();
        return result;
    }
    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() { return used == 0; }
    public synchronized boolean isFull() { return used == size; }
}
```

Comment: Fixed: notifyAll() added to put()

Comment: It's a FIFO queue.  It's a circular queue.

Comment: Wow, who's downvoting this?  This code works perfectly.

Comment: I doen't work - it keeps waiting.

Comment: I've tested it.  It will wait if you overfill or call take() when it's empty.  I've made edits.  Perhaps you are using an old edit.

Comment: No, there's a bug. Create a queue of size 10, then fill 10 elements, then try to display them.

Comment: Fixed for that case and hopefully for all cases.

Comment: Not yet. If i fill half the queue, then try to print all, it hangs.

Comment: Like this?  It works:

    Queue<String> queue = new Queue<String>(10);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println(queue.take());
    }

Comment: fill 5, then try to take 10 - hangs.

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work.  It is supposed to hang when it's empty until you supply it with more entries (in another thread).  This is EXACTLY the way ArrayBlockingQueue works.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue is the fastest if blocking is not required.

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue has higher throughput since put() and take() are synchronized using 2 different locks except when edge condition of Queue = empty / full is reached